# Need help converting iterative pattern into formula

Tags: math, recursion, iteration, analytical

```
var = 8

itr 1:
var == 8 (8 * 1)

itr 2:
var == 24 (8 * 3)

itr 3:
var == 48 (8 * 6)

itr 4:
var == 80 (8 * 10)

itr 5:
var == 120 (8 * 15)
```

Pattern: (var * (last multiplier + current iteration))

Basically I want to get the result of formula(itr) without having to iterate up to itr.

Comment: I'll venture a guess that this is your homework.  What have you tried so far?  Any pseduo-code that you can share?

Comment: Smells a little like homework... are you asking for the answer, or help discovering the answer?

Comment: Has nothing to do with homework, has to do with a prediction algorithm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value of `var` in the `nth` iteration is 8 times the sum of 1..n. The sum of 1..n is given by the formula `(n)(n+1)/2`; for example, the sum from 1..6 is 6*7/2 = **21**.

Thus, **`var == 4(i)(i+1)`** on the `ith` iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Use [triangular numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_numbers).

Answer (score 0):

Multiply 8 by the sum of 1 to the current iteration:

```
>>> def itr(n): return 8 * sum(xrange(n+1))
...
>>> itr(1)
8
>>> itr(2)
24
>>> itr(3)
48
>>> itr(4)
80
>>> itr(5)
120
```